# ¿Cómo modificar elementos de un modal al hacer clic en otro elemento?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, modal

Mi situación en la siguiente. Tengo un plugin de WordPress que genera un modal para editar cierta información, que aparece al hacer clic en un icono. Se ve la siguiente manera:

[image: modal]

El caso es que quiero que cuando se haga clic en el icono del reloj se haga algún cambio en los elementos del modal. Por ejemplo, cambiar el texto de la pregunta o del titulo o incluso introducir otro elemento a voluntad.

He intentado con lo siguiente (la sintaxis del código es porque estoy agregándolo a WordPress):

```js
jQuery('#cf7d-edit-form').on('click',function(){
            let titulo_modal = document.getElementById("TB_ajaxWindowTitle");
            titulo_modal.innerHTML = "Esto es una prueba";
    });
```

Para modificar por ejemplo el texto del titulo del modal pero no funciona. Asumo que es porque al momento de hacer clic en el icono, el código HTML del modal, que es este:

```html
<div id="TB_title"><div id="TB_ajaxWindowTitle">Edit Information.</div><div id="TB_closeAjaxWindow"><button type="button" id="TB_closeWindowButton"><span class="screen-reader-text">Cerrar</span><span class="tb-close-icon"></span></button></div></div>
```

donde está el "id=TB_ajaxWindowTitle" aún no existe y se crea posteriormente. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer a la función esperar que el código del modal se genere para que haga el resto?

Pude conseguir que se cambiara el texto en el titulo con esto:

```js
let modificacion = function(){
                let titulo_modal = document.getElementById("TB_ajaxWindowTitle");
                titulo_modal.innerHTML = "Esto es una prueba.";
            };
    setTimeout(modificacion, 10000);
```

Pero colocandolo fuera de cualquier función. Lo que necesito es que se haga luego de algunos segundos de hacer clic en el icono del reloj. Al como (que no funciona tampoco):

```js
jQuery('#cf7d-edit-form').on('click',function(){
        let modificacion = function(){
                let titulo_modal = document.getElementById("TB_ajaxWindowTitle");
                titulo_modal.innerHTML = "Esto es una prueba.";
            };
    setTimeout(modificacion, 10000);
    });
```

donde "cf7d-edit-form" es el id del icono al que se le hace clic.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me pillas muy verde con wordpress, pero hacer esperar a una función es bastante simple: `sleep(500).then(() => { funcionQueEspera() });`

Comment: Genial. Entonces debería hacer que la función que modifica los elementos, espere X segundos después de hacer clic en el icono, con lo que propones. Pero cómo hago que eso se ejecute después de un clic en otro elemento?  Gracias por responder

Comment: Cuando haces click en ese elemento debe de tener alguna forma de ejecutar la función que llama al modal. si por ejemplo es un `onclick(funcionUno())` lo modificas por esto `onclick(funcionUno();sleep(500).then(() => { funcionQueEspera() }))` o puedes buscar la función que crea esos modals y añadirlo allí

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que precisamente no quiero hacer la modificación en el código original del plugin. Por eso estoy haciendo un plugin que hace varias modificaciones y entre ellas esta la de cambiar elementos de ese modal.

Comment: Se me ocurrió intentar con esto: jQuery('#cf7d-edit-form').on('click',function(){
        let modificacion = function(){
            let titulo_modal = document.getElementById("TB_ajaxWindowTitle");
            titulo_modal.innerHTML = "Esto es una prueba.";
       };
        setTimeout(modificacion, 3000);
    });  Pero tampoco funcionó. Esto lo hago desde un archivo JS que cargó desde el plugin que estoy creando.

Comment: Entiendo... Deja algo de código en la pregunta, como para que se entienda que y de donde salen `cf7d-edit-form` y `TB_ajaxWindowTitle`

Comment: Ya dejé algo más de información. Gracias.

Comment: Una duda, cuando dices que no funciona es que no hace nada, ni un error en la consola? Si pones `console.erro('algo')` dentro de las funciones te printea algo? Por cierto, puedes usar ** y ` entre otros para marcar texto y código en vez de usar las "

Comment: Si, no hace absolutamente nada. Ya probé eso para ver si da error pero no encontré nada. Gracias por el tip para marcar código.

Comment: Ok, entonces el problema es otro muy diferente. El problema es que no te está funcionando el código de `Jquery(...` pero aquí ya no te se decir, con wordpres me pierdo